# How can I set default value of transient to hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I'm trying to create factory with transient attribute, when I set its default value to hash I get some syntax errors:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    transient do 
      location {city: nil, state: nil, country: "Polska"}
    end

    name "MyString"
    start_date Date.today+2
    start_time "17:40"
    location_raw "MyLocation"
    description "MyText"
    website "MyString"


    after(:create) do |event, evaluator|
      Location.find_or_create_by(evaluator.location).events << event
    end
  end
end
```

When I set it to `nil`, it works ok.

```
transient do 
  location nil
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Errors are:

```
/home/marcin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load': /home/marcin/Projects/StreetballKalendarz.pl/spec/factories/events.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' (SyntaxError)
      location {city: nil, state: nil, country: "Polska"}
                     ^
/home/marcin/Projects/StreetballKalendarz.pl/spec/factories/events.rb:4: Can't assign to nil
      location {city: nil, state: nil, country: "Polska"}
                          ^
/home/marcin/Projects/StreetballKalendarz.pl/spec/factories/events.rb:4: Can't assign to nil
      location {city: nil, state: nil, country: "Polska"}
```

Comment: Not certain on this but factory girl evaluates between the braces.   Try adding a second set `location { { city: nil, state: nil, country: "Polska" } }`

Comment: Thanks, you're right. If you want add an answer, so I could accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factory girl evaluates between the braces. So I think you need a second set to make it understand it's a hash

```
location { { city: nil, state: nil, country: "Polska" } }
```

Comment: Another way to avoid FactoryGirl thinking your curly braces are a block is by giving it parentheses,  `location({ .. })`